# How to implement recurrence functionality by using quartz scheduler?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have scenario to implement recurrence functionality by using Quartz Scheduler. The end user will give an input like Week Days (Monday to Friday) or Month(January to December) or Day (1 to 31),Start Date and Recurrence. 
 Example : 
 Week Days : Tuesday  or  Month : January or Day : 19
 Start Date : 01/19/2015
 Recurrence :4

In the above example, if user is selected weekdays as Tuesday, start date and recurrence. Hence Quartz Job should run 4 times i.e Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday and Friday.

How can I achieve recurrence functionality by using quart scheduler?

Comment: I found solution to implement for recurrence functionality. First we need find out the end date as per input recurrence(10).
Here is the piece of code to find end date

CronTrigger trigger = newTrigger().withSchedule(scheduleBuilder).build();
Date endDateCalResult=TriggerUtils.computeEndTimeToAllowParticularNumberOfFirings((OperableTrigger) trigger, new BaseCalendar(java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone()), 10);

Comment: i.e. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26327264/3883957) answer