# Quartz Scheduler : Is it possible to build a recurring trigger specified with a duration *before* a time point?

Tags: quartz-scheduler

How could I approach building a recurring trigger in Quartz that fires some N duration *before* particular time point?

The best example of this would be a meeting reminder.  Imagine you have a recurring meeting at 11 AM on the 1st of every month, and you want a reminder event to be dispatched 24 hours prior to that.

I can't see how to solve this with the usual "start at this time point, then repeat with this interval".

I feel like this is a common enough scenario that some solution already exists in a popular scheduling library like Quartz.  I'm really seeking a solution that allows expressing such triggers as some kind a runtime configuration.

Comment: In your example, what don't you set recurring trigger for the last day of every month at 11AM?

Comment: Alternatively, maybe http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/TriggerUtils.html would help you? You can find an example of usage in my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/26327264/3883957.